# Автоматическая прокрутка текста в Layout

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, прошу подсказать как сделать автоматическую прокрутку текста снизу вверх, хочу чтоб текст двигался плавно в лайауте до определенного момента и чтоб можно было его обратно пролистать если нужно.

Comment: Оберните ваш `TextView` в `ScrollView` и программно скроллите его. Вам надо крутить до какого-то определённого текста? Тогда лучше использовать список. Разделить текст на части и крутить список на нужный айтем

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можете еще подсказать как сделать, чтобы определенный TextView появлялся динамически в процессе просмотра страницы? Поясню я хочу сделать простенький текстовый квест и хочу чтоб новые сообщения по сюжету появлялись постепенно. Может посоветуете что использовать?

Comment: А как программно скролить список?

Comment: Все же используете список? Если да то вы можете использовать `smoothScrollToPosition` у `ListView` или у `RecyclerView`

Comment: Советую вам начать гуглить по английски. Очень много находится :)